# Images are not loading in email sending through php

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have given a full path of images for mail sending option. Images are loading in browser, but not loading in mails.I have used PHP mail function. Any one can  help me regarding this issue.? I have used CSP login for browser credentials.

My code is look like:

```
<?php
$NewMsg .="<p><img src='http://chradm18.gcsc.att.com/itmsmaps/images/Banner.png' alt='' style='width:800px;height:50px'></p>";
$to  = "abc.intl.com";
$subject="ITMS MAPS";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ITMS MAPS' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $NewMsg, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: I can not see your code here.

Comment: Dont forget to use absolute paths like: http://my-website.com/images/image01.jpg

Comment: I have used full path of image like   http://chradm18.gcsc.att.com/itmsmaps/images/new.png  .. In some server it is working fine.. In some server it is not loading.. I have given all the file permissions.

Comment: Sorry, but you're out of luck. Today is "Everyone send their magic crystal balls into the shop for maintenance day", so no one can read your mind to see what your code looks like. Try again next week.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using an SMTP service like SendGrid to send your emails. There is a lot of added ease and functionality provided by these services.

Some local ISPs block port 25 (SMTP) and I found that instead of spending hours trying to figure out every new issue in sending email, moving to a service like SendGrid was easier and far more reliable in ensuring my emails were being delivered.

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php#usage

```
<?php
require 'vendor/sendgrid-php.php';

$sendgrid = new SendGrid("username", "password", array("turn_off_ssl_verification" => true));

$email    = new SendGrid\Email();
$email->addTo("hello@world.com")->
       setFrom("me@world.com")->
       setSubject('Test Email Image')->
       setHtml('<img src='http://chradm18.gcsc.att.com/itmsmaps/images/Banner.png' alt='' style='width:800px;height:50px'>')->       
       addHeader('X-Sent-Using', 'SendGrid-API')->
       addHeader('X-Transport', 'web');

$response = $sendgrid->send($email);
var_dump($response);

?>
```